# SAS XML-mapper Input length = 1 message

Tags: xml, sas

For one of my XML-files i get the following Message when opening the file in SAS XML-mappper: `Input length = 1 ('Close' is the only button).`

After generating Automatic XML mapping, I can run the program in SAS BASE, but I get a few errors:

```
ERROR: Some code points did not transcode.
       occurred at or near line 1, column 2701665
ERROR: XML parsing error. Please verify that the XML content is well-formed.
```

All in all, I seem to get 3915 out of  3971 observations, which I suppose are dropped because of the Error. I have identified some of the dropped cases, but there doesnt seem to be anything strange With these cases. They look just like any other cases. I have no idea where to begin troubleshooting. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your XML file well-formed?  I would be concerned that some of the records aren't complete.

Comment: Can you open your XML file in Excel and view those records?

Comment: Yes, I have taken a look at the records in question, but there doesnt seem to be anything wrong with them. There is nothing missing or misplaced.

Comment: Could be a line buffer limit, try putting in a few crlf into the file to test if that fixes the issue. Also, make sure the XML-Mapper is the same version as delivered to your version of sas. The schema def can be incompatible if those two products are not exactly in sync.

Comment: I see now that XML mapper is version 9.4, while my SAS base version is 9.3. Hope this problem is fixed once we upgrade to 9.4. Tank you, never would have thought that could cause problems